# ошибка в render_template python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

1). У меня есть выпадающий список из мейлов пользователей. Когда я выбираю один из них, появляется модальное окно с этим мейлом, и я могу отправить сообщение на него. Получаю я его туда с помощью `ajax`. Но при отправке я получаю сообщение об ошибке: `"NoneType" object is not a subscription`. В чем проблема? мой объект не пустой. Он печатается в консоли.

2). Вторая проблема в том, что я не могу получить свои `born_date` и `phone_number` на странице из бд, хотя я могу принтовать их в консоли. Проблема в `render_template`. Как это решить?

Структура базы данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('Holy Shit!')
        data = request.json
        print(str_value_to_list(data['selectedItems'][0]))

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = '%s'" % 
    str_value_to_list(data['selectedItems'][0]))
    account = cur.fetchone()
    born = account[0]
    num = account[1]
    print(born)
    print(num)
    return render_template('profile.html', born=born, num=num)
```

`html`

```html
<form action="profile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="container reg" style="width: 45%;">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <p class="white-text" style="color: #000;">Search your email</p>
            <br>


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="process();"
                style="background:#3E75A5; border: 1px solid #285F8F;">
                Get Info
            </button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function printValue(selectedItem) {
                    $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value);
                }
            </script>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Information about user</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p class="form-control" id="mySelectedValue" style="margin-top: 10px;"></p>

                            <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add your message here"
                                required="required">

                            <h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">born: {{ born }}</h2>
                            <h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">num: {{ num }}</h2>

                            <button class="btn btn-primary send">
                                Send
                            </button>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function printValue(selectedItem) {
                    $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value.replace(/[{()}]/g, '').replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/[{,}]/g, ''));
                    console.log(selectedItem.value);
                }
                function process(selectedItem) {
                    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show')
                    document.getElementById('#exampleModalCenter')
                    const data = JSON.stringify({
                        "selectedItems": $('#sel').val()
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/profile",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                    });
                }
                function optionClick(selectedItem) {
                    printValue(selectedItem);
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: а что в консоли выводит `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: А как вы ожидаете получить JSON объект от метода `profile`, если вы ничего подобного не возвращаете? Ваш метод возвращает только отрендеренный шаблон (во всех случаях), а ajax-запрос ждет возвращаемого JSON.

Comment: Не пишите два вопроса в одном обращении! У них могут быть разные причины и способы решения. Вопросы следует разделить

Comment: @cauf я получаю его в profile через data = request.json

Comment: @cauf эти вопросы связаны друг с другом, поэтому задал

Comment: Не связаны. Во всяком случае напрямую. Вы не возвращаете валидный ответ для ajax-запроса. Когда вы выполняете команду `$.ajax({url: "/profile", ... })`, ожидается, что указанный метод `profile` возвращает валидный JSON-объект. то есть, что метод в вашем приложении вернет `return jsonify(data)`, но у вас в методе есть только `return render_template(...)`, который возвращает совсем не то, что нужно.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin я получаю Json объект вида: {«selectedItems”:”firstname”, “lastname”, “mymail@gmail.com”}

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110551/discussion-between-cauf-and-abby).

Comment: @cauf, я все послал вам в чате. посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @cauf сможете помочь?

Comment: @cauf, ответил, проверьте

Comment: @abby скинул пример в чат

Comment: @cauf ответил в чат

Comment: @cauf, можете посмотреть пожалуйста. Может вы можете помочь с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158468/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0-json-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)