# получение ключа json объекта из базы данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, flask

У меня есть бд, из которой я получаю данные пользователей и записываю их в `json` файл.

Вот [структура](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH7hX.jpg):

Проблема в том, что я получаю сразу значение. Как получать еще и ключ, чтобы было не просто

```
[
    54,
    "newuser",
    "newuser",
    "newuser@mail.ru",
    "2020-06-30",
    "qweqwe123",
    123123123,
    "description"
],
```

а вот так:

```
{
    "id": "54",
    "firstname": "newuser",
    "lastname": "newuser",
    "email": "newuser@mail.ru",
    "born_date": "qweqwe123",
    "password": "34962",
    "phone_number": "123123123",
    "description": "description"
},
```

вот код:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        phone_number = request.form['number']
        born_date = request.form['date']
        description = request.form['description']

        # password = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
        # password = password.hexdigest()

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = %s AND password = %s',
                    (email, password))

        account = cur.fetchone() # get all in account variable

        if account:
            return render_template('exist.html')
        else:
            session['email'] = email
            session['firstname'] = firstname
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(firstname, lastname, email, born_date, password, phone_number, description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
                                                (firstname, lastname, email, born_date, password, phone_number, description))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()

            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, born_date, password, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE description = 'doctor'") # тут добавить выбор id, born_date, password, phone_number
            account = cur.fetchall()
            description = account
            cur.close()

            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users.data")
            account = cur.fetchall()
            description = account
            content = {}
            content = description
            with open('data_json.json', 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(content, json_file, indent=4)

            return render_template('profile.html', email=session['email'], firstname=session['firstname'], description=description)
return render_template('register.html')
```

я сделал так:

```
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users.data")
    account = cur.fetchone()
    description = account
    content = {'id': description[0], 'firstname': description[1], 'lastname': description[2], 'email': description[3], 'born_date': description[4], 
                'password': description[5], 'phone_number': description[6], 'description': description[7]}
    content = description
    with open('data_json.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(content, json_file, indent=4)
```

и получил, то, что хотел, но только для одного юзера. когда для всех `fetchall()` пишу, не срабатывает так

Comment: вы бы приложили файл с примером, а не текстовую интерпретацию. а также код, с помощью которого вы получаете данные без ключей

Comment: @Александр, в том примере все есть, но я обновил весь код. проверьте

Comment: @Александр можете помочь с решением?

Comment: Тут есть тонкость, которую заметил разбираясь с задачей парсинга в json.
Используя конструкцию firstname = request.form['firstname'] вы теряете сам ключ "firstname".
Связано это с тем, что типы json и типы, используемые в Python не совпадают.

Comment: Используйте сборку данных,  при которых у вас получится набор данных имеющих тип: <class 'dict'>.

Comment: @abby Предлагаю вернуться в [этот чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110551/discussion-between-cauf-and-abby)

Comment: @Assur, я обновил код. посмотрите

Comment: `pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` в помощь